# Is it possible to use environment variable (e.g. $HOME ) in auditctl ? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: home-directory, environment-variables

I'm trying to monitor `/home/<user>/` folder.

I created `# auditctl -w $HOME -p rwxa -k home_access` rule. But it creates rule only for current user.

**Is it possible to create such a rule that monitors $HOME folder for all users?**

Comment: `$HOME` will be expanded by your interactive shell at the time you execute the command. I guess if all your users' home directories are in `/home` you could just monitor that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked several questions in one, so here are several answers, hopefully covering all of them.

1. Yes, it is possible to use environment variables in `auditctl` just like in every other command.
2. When using environment variables, you need to be aware how the shell interprets them: it reads the content of the variable at the time the command is invoked, and inserts them in the command line in the place of the variable. If the content of the variable changes later, that has no effect. Hence, the command
   `auditctl -w $HOME -p rwxa -k home_access`
   will monitor the folder named by `$HOME` at the time (and context) the command was run, no matter what `$HOME` may contain later (or in a different context).
3. The `auditctl` command will only monitor a single folder. (The one given after `-w`.) If you want to monitor several folders, you'll have to invoke it several times.
4. It is possible to create a *set* of rules that monitors the `$HOME` directories of all users. For this you'll have to read the list of users, determine each user's `$HOME`, and feed that to an `auditctl` command in a loop. This is a little exercise in `bash` scripting.
5. You may also want to specify precisely what you mean by "all users". Are system users like `root` or `avahi` to be included in that monitoring?
6. As an easy special case, if you just want to monitor those `$HOME` directories residing in the top level directory `/home` (and *all* of those) then you could instead just enter:
   `auditctl -w /home -p rwxa -k home_access`
   and be done with it.
   This will also monitor the directory `/home` itself (ie. creation and deletion of home directories) but perhaps that's tolerable.